# How to install recent version of Docker in OpenSuse Leap 42.1

Tags: opensuse, docker

Latest available version of Docker in official OpenSuse repos is 1.9.1.
Latest version of Docker is 1.11.2 with a lot of changes from 1.9.1.

I've tried to do a [manual installation of latest binaries](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/binaries/), but no success.
It tells me:

```
Udev sync is not supported. 
This will lead to unexpected behavior, data loss and errors
```

I've also looked in the repositories for more modern versions, but no luck.

With other Linux distributions like CentOS 7, I've had no problems.

How can I install it?

Comment: Have you tried their unstabled offerings, like v1.11.1 and v1.12?

Comment: I have tried to 1 click install of unstable packages by using: https://software.opensuse.org/package/docker, but it fails.

Comment: Have you tried Docker's scripts?  Point a browser at https://get.docker.com/ and take a look at their process.  Usually the first or second examples work well (depends on whether you're using curl or wget) for most Linux instances.

Comment: Lately the OpenSuse gets recent updates, the latest available version is 1.12.1

Answer (score 0):

After a few months, the situation has improved a lot.  Docker packages for OpenSuse get recent updates quite often.  The latest available version is 1.12.1, that is the more recent Docker version that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Docker 1.12.3 is the latest release package available for OpenSuSE Leap 42.2. I tested it on Raspberry Pi yesterday and it works flawlessly.Check out my latest blog http://collabnix.com/archives/2431

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: Here's the working link : http://collabnix.com/test-drive-docker-1-12-on-first-64-bit-arm-os-running-on-raspberry-pi-3/